# cannot setVisible after setIcon is called google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have two listener methods : "zoom_changer" and "show_viewport".

1)zoom_changer listens 'zoom_changed' event and set size of icons wrt zoom level.

2)show_viewport listens 'idle' event and set visibility of icons wrt visible bounds of map because I want to prevent heavy loading and make panning and zooming more smoother

The problem occurs when I change the zoom of map. After changing zoom of map,'show_viewport' function works and hide some icons wrt viewport but cannot set visible when icons enter the viewport again. When I disable zoom_changer and use icons with their original sizes , 'show_viewport' works perfectly. Thanks in advance.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    var multiply;
    var zoom_pix = {3: 8, 2: 4, 1: 2, 0: 2}
    multiply = zoom_pix[Math.max(0, zoom - 17)]
    if (zoom != previous_zoom) {
        for (let i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) {

            map.markers[i].setIcon({
                url: String(map.markers[i].icon),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(multiply * 8, multiply * 8)
            });

        }
        previous_zoom = zoom;
    }});};
```

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

        for (let i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) {
            if (map.getBounds().contains(map.markers[i].getPosition()) && !map.markers[i].getVisible()) {
                map.markers[i].setVisible(true);

                
            } else if (!map.getBounds().contains(map.markers[i].getPosition()) && map.markers[i].getVisible()) {
                map.markers[i].setVisible(false);
                
            }
        }



    });

};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question. In further questions, I will provide snippets. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `marker.icon` is not (always) a `String` on this line:

```
url: String(map.markers[i].icon),
```

(it is an `Object`, at least in my test case)

Instead do (using documented methods and properties, not an undocumented property):

```
url: map.markers[i].getIcon().url,
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c0w61p9q/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
// Sydney, NSW, Australia. Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond
// to the base of the flagpole.
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: -33.9,
      lng: 151.2
    },
  });
  setMarkers(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) {
      if (map.getBounds().contains(map.markers[i].getPosition()) && !map.markers[i].getVisible()) {
        map.markers[i].setVisible(true);
      } else if (!map.getBounds().contains(map.markers[i].getPosition()) && map.markers[i].getVisible()) {
        map.markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  });
  var previous_zoom;
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    var multiply;
    var zoom_pix = {
      3: 8,
      2: 4,
      1: 2,
      0: 2
    }
    multiply = zoom_pix[Math.max(0, zoom - 17)]
    if (zoom != previous_zoom) {
      for (let i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) {
        map.markers[i].setIcon({
          url: map.markers[i].getIcon().url,
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(multiply * 8, multiply * 8)
        });
      }
      previous_zoom = zoom;
    }
  });
}
// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
// order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
const beaches = [
  ["Bondi Beach", -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ["Coogee Beach", -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ["Cronulla Beach", -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ["Manly Beach", -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ["Maroubra Beach", -33.950198, 151.259302, 1],
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  if (!map.markers)
    map.markers = [];
  // Adds markers to the map.

  for (let i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    const beach = beaches[i];
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: beach[1],
        lng: beach[2]
      },
      map: map,
      title: beach[0],
      icon: {url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"}
    });
    map.markers.push(marker);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Complex Marker Icons</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In my case , I used ImageMarker function to use icon urls so I have to get url as a string from object "map.markers[i].getIcon()" with map.markers[i].getIcon().url and it worked.

Comment: That was an error, fixed my answer.